# Can an aws target be triggered by multiple cloudwatch event rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, rules, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I'm trying to set up a scheduler system for our infrastructure that suppose to take care of all scheduled housekeeping tasks. Our proposal is to make it simple and scalable with one docker image. A Script of each task and cloudWatch event rule will be passed in as parameters. The scripts will be uploaded on an s3 bucket and will be downloaded when the job gets triggered. This way we can avoid redeploying every time a task gets added.
The only tricky park is to pass in cloudWatch event rule as parameter.
Can an event target be triggered by multiple rules? Am I too ambitious on this project? I use terraform to provision it.

Comment: Yes, you can trigger a target by multiple events or rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn Cloud watch logs on
2. Create a metric filter
3. Assign a metric
4. Create alarm.

Here is a tutorial which you can modify to suit your needs.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-receive-notifications-when-your-aws-accounts-root-access-keys-are-used/